# Need help to find previous year rolling to a specific date in power BI

Tags: dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server, daxstudio

[Link to Image: Please check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z1HO.jpg) I have to make a monthly trending view to show trend from a specific date for rolling 12 months and same period in the prior year. I am unable to get them side by side to help me visualize on a line chart.Can someone check my DAX code and please share a correct way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
Z.Closed Won $ PY R12 =
VAR cdate =
    MAX ( 'Close Date'[Report Date] )
VAR previousdate =
    DATE ( YEAR ( cdate ) - 1, MONTH ( cdate ), DAY ( cdate ) )
VAR result =
    CALCULATE (
        [Closed Won Opportunities $],
        FILTER (
            'Close Date',
            'Close Date'[Date] <= cdate
                && 'Close Date'[Date] > previousdate
        )
    )
RETURN
    result
```

Comment: Actually, what I am trying to do is as below :

I have a specific date, which is 16th Aug-2022, from where I am to calculate rolling 12 months period and compare that to previous period. Current Period - 16th Aug-2022 to 17th Aug 2021 and Previous Period - 16th Aug-2021 to 17th Aug 2022. And then I want to visualize this over a single time-period chart as these will be two separate lines. What I am currently getting with the above code is numbers for Current period and not Previous.

Comment: Hello @Vinayak It doesn't work like as you said. Let's say we have now 16th Aug-2022, and above code will cover the date range:16th Aug-2022 / 16th Aug-2021. If the current period is 16th Aug-2021, and previous period It will cover is 1 year back: 16th Aug-2021 / 16th Aug-2020. You know why? Because check  previousdate variable. we defined it as 1 year back as you have also written in your original code.